# Atom Flatpak using sandboxed runtimes and executables in package settings

Tags: php, atom-editor, sandbox, runtime, flatpak

I'm using the flatpak version of Atom. I want to install a linting package for PHP, so that code errors are easier to spot. However it requires access to a php binary.

Now since this is a Flatpak, it's sandboxed so no chance of me giving it proper access to the `/usr/bin` directory any time soon, but I discovered I could use a Flatpak runtime of PHP 7.4 called `org.freedesktop.Sdk.Extension.php74`, which should provide me with what I need.

The only question that's left for me is how do I pass this to the package? The setting I'm provided with is a path text field, where I'd normally pass it the `/usr/bin/php` path, but how do I invoke the flatpak equivalent to that?

Answer (score 0):

So I found some closure with this and here's what I found.

It turns out the correct way to pass `php`, for example, is to add it with the path `/var/run/host/usr/bin/phpX.X`, where `X.X` is the particular version of PHP you would have. In my case it was `/var/run/host/usr/bin/php8.0`.

Because the Flatpak sandbox mounts the `/usr` directory in a limited manner, to allow flatpaks access to certain system binaries they might need, running just the equivalent of `/usr/bin/php` would not be sufficient, the specific binary with the specific version number is required.

There is, however, still an issue. The Flatpak sandbox itself appears to not mount things properly, I believe this is a known issue. Two php libraries - `libargon2` and `libsodium` are not found by the PHP binary. I attempted to change the `LD_LIBRARY_PATH` to try properly include them, but to no avail.

This problem persisted with PHP versions as far back as 7.1.

In the end I moved to the Debian package of Atom, since I cannot figure this out, but if this issue gets resolved in the Flatpak sandbox, I'll be moving back to that and the solutions above are more than sufficent.